# Transformer.transform is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After upgrading react-native from 0.48.3 to 0.62.2 I get the error when running "react-native run-ios" command: "index.js: Transformer.transform is not a function".

Comment: Did you search for that exact error message on the web? [Edit] this question and tell us why the many solutions found there don't apply here (if they do not).

Comment: You should look through the change log of any of the libraries that were upgraded, particularly related to the transform function or Transformer object. Also, this is not a question....